# How to port C#  Console application to Windows Phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, web-services, windows-phone-7

Basically, the console application consumes a web service, and I want to do the same with windows phone application. I know that things work differently with WP7 with respect to web services, and I would like to know if this is possible.

The console version uses the namespace System.Web.Services which is not allowed for the wp7. How else could I achieve the same?

Comment: If you're new to Windows Phone 7, I suggest you read Charles Petzold's free e-book [Programming Windows Phone 7](http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone/index.html).

Comment: @Bernard Great reference, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to write a WCF service and using that service you can execute all the functionality that you want to do via console application.

Then refer that WCF service into your wp7 app and you are done. There are lot of help available online, here are 2. Hope this will help you.

[Link1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andypennell/archive/2010/09/20/using-wcf-on-windows-phone-7-walk-through.aspx)

[Link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg598947)