# Is it possible to develop a console mode application for Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, console-application

I have a console application that I would like to port to Windows Phone 8. Is it possible to run a console mode on WP8 ?
I saw the [MS-DOS mobile](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/ms-dos-mobile/8573c4a8-b9df-4409-90a6-dad2dc0b6b26) app but I wonder if it is just a simulated console mode.

I also saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003634/how-to-port-c-sharp-console-application-to-windows-phone) question but it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing like a text mode for Windows Phone. You have to simulate it yourself.